# ajax auto refresh div hides div after x seconds

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a problem, I want reload my `<div>` content every 5 seconds. I am sure some days ago it was working and I have nothing changed on code.

After 5 seconds, the `<div>` disappears and the content is not updated. Just away my complete  `<div>`.

My code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval("myx_function();",5000); 
    function myx_function() {
        $('#refresh').load(location.href + ' #time');
    }
</script>

<div id="refresh">
    <div id="time">
        <?php echo date('H:i:s');?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone know the problem?

Comment: Try to erite your setIntervall() call to `setInterval(myx_function,5000);` Also, are you sure the space before `#time` is correct? Maybe it should be `location.href + '#time'`. But still I think this is a bit strange to load the site and go to an anchor, not sure wether this should really work.

Comment: Yes without space before #time its show the whole page like an iframe in the div class and also setinterval from you dont work. Its the same, hides div after 5 seconds

Comment: Alright, now I understand how `#time` is supposed to work. Try to log the response you get from that call: `$('#refresh').load(location.href + ' #time', function (response, status, xhr) { console.log(response)});`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the Problem.

My Page starts with:

```
if (isset($_POST......{

}else{
        header("Location: ./");
        return false;
}
```

If i remove the

```
else{
            header("Location: ./");
            return false;
    }
```

It works again. I must solve it on other way the redirect.